# Delimiting a column using "OR" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, csv, textjoin

I am using google sheets and would like to combine the text in cells of a column to a single cell separated by "OR" (with spaces on either side of the OR"
For example

```
**Column A**
John
Bob
Jim
Donald
```

would be combined in a single cell as "John OR Bob OR Jim OR Donald"
What formula in Google Sheets would I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=JOIN(" OR ", A1:A4)
```

[image: 0]

or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" OR ", 1, A:A)
```

[image: 0]

---

if you hit the limit try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1&" "&QUERY(IF(A2:A<>"", "OR "&A2:A, ),,999^99))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=textjoin(" OR ", 1, A2:A)
```

Change range to suit.